# Background image and scrollview on react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am building an app using react native and wants to achieve a background image and a scrollview which overlays on top of the background image like the yahoo weather app.

But I can't get it to work.

Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get this effect, you need to set an absolutely positioned image, then place a ScrollView on top of the View:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  Image
} = React;

let width = Dimensions.get('window').width

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
        <View>
            <Image style={{ height: width, width: width, position: 'absolute', top:0, left:0 }} source={{ uri: 'http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/32297951629_5/5pcs-lot-The-Hollowan-Star-Nicolas-Cage-Stylish-Square-Pillowcase-Cushion-Pillow-Cover.jpg' }} />
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={{ flex:1 }}>
          <View>
            <Text>{ipsum}</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 28,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    fontSize: 19,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);

let ipsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```

Comment: But now, I need the app to be able to swipe horizontally to have the next image with similar layout with the first page.
any ideas?

Comment: With React Native 0.18.1, some of the style attributes in this example are not even needed. Here is a stripped down example: [https://gist.github.com/alexbepple/ded4d0f0798ad0165c44](https://gist.github.com/alexbepple/ded4d0f0798ad0165c44) It also features more text to illustrate scrolling on larger devices and a lighter background image.